# How to design a “Postgreql-like” table for a website?

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

I'm a developper, and this is my first question on graphic design.

For a website, I want to design a table in the way postgresql (or mysql, or other) do:

```
    name    | height | first_man 
------------+--------+-----------
 everest    |   8848 | hillary
 mont blanc |   4810 | balmat
```

I've started a codepen for this.

We need to do three things:

1 - add pipes ('|') : I've discovered the ::after for this

2 - add dashes ('-') : I don't want to use the border dashed since I want to be able to use other chars (eg '=' for total)

3 - add pluses ('+') in the crossings

Comment: You should start by evaluating the available table/grid components/libraries and decide what's most important for your project (cell editing, pagination, offline/online data sources, searching, filtering, auto-filters, automated/manual summary rows, sub-grids, tree-grids, ...).

Comment: I just need a web design advise here: are the "-" and "+" in the html or css? if in the css, how to write it?

Answer (score 0):

Et voilà!

See solution here: http://codepen.io/bixente57/pen/JKQjpg

The code:

```
<table class="brutal">
  <thead class="brutal data">
    <td>name</td>
    <td>height</td>
    <td class="last">first_man</rd>
  </thead>
  <tr class="line">
    <td>-----------</td>
    <td>-----------</td>
    <td class="last">--------------</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="data">
    <td>mont blanc</td>
    <td>4810</td>
    <td class="last">Balmat</rd>
  </tr>
  <tr class="data">
    <td>everest</td>
    <td>8848</td>
    <td class="last">hillary</rd>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table.brutal{
  font-family:courier;
}
table.brutal thead {
  text-align:center;
}
table.brutal td{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

table.brutal .data td:not(.last)::after {
  content:'|';
  float:right;
}
table.brutal .line td:not(.last)::after {
  content:'+';
  float:right;
  padding-top:1px;
}
```

Can you comment on the CSS/HTML code? (I don't know the best practices, maybe there are some refractories/ style to improve?)